# Stop do until loop if only all cells in range are filled

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is exiting the do until loop once all the cells in the range are filled. So far I only manage to make it stop when one cell is filled.

```
do until 

do something()

for each cel in range("A1:A20")

   if isEmpty(cel.value)=true then

   else

exit do

  end if

next

loop
```

Comment: Your code currently doesn't make any sense, which makes your question pretty much unanswerable IMO. Why not include your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the shortest (not necessarily fastest/best) code I can think of

```
Do Until Range("A1:A20").Find("") Is Nothing
    '...
Loop
```

Might want to set the `Find` parameters beforehand though I'm not sure if it makes a difference when searching for `""`

If possible, it would be safer to loop over all the cells, because you can't end up with an endless loop.

```
For Each cel in Range("A1:A20")
    If Range("A1:A20").Find("") Is Nothing Then Exit For
    'do your thing
Next cel
```

or if your actions only affect the current cell:

```
For Each cel in Range("A1:A20")
    If Not IsEmpty(cel) Then
        'do your thing
    End If
Next cel
```

If your range is very large and you expect to reach the point where all cells are filled early on, then the `.Find` method might be faster although there are better methods than to loop over large ranges...

Comment: Thanks but im checking to see if all cells are filled then once all are filled the loop should stop

Comment: Did you try it? It does exactly what you described. If all cells are filled, `.Find("")` finds nothing and returns `Nothing`.

Comment: it stops the loop before all cells can be filled. because im writing to the cells of the selected range. once filled the loop should stop and exit

Comment: Do you have formulas in the range that produce empty cells? Do you want these cells to count as empty or not? `IsEmpty` looks at the formula as well btw. Other than that `Range("A1:A20").Find("") Is Nothing` only evaluates to true if there are no empty cells so the loop can't stop by itself before that. If `Range("A1:A20")` is the wrong range you are the only one who can fix that...

Comment: it stops everytime A2 is filled

Comment: I did forget to add is nothing but now the loops doesn't stop and crashing excel

Comment: I can't help you there, you have to make sure that sooner or later all cells are filled. I'll edit another solution into my answer.

Comment: @user1922856 When you're dealing with `While` / `Do Until` loops and aren't sure if it works yet, set a breakpoint or step through the code line by line (using F8) to see if it's working without having to kill the process.

Comment: How do you translate Point *V to get V[I].y I being iteration of a loop and y the a range of cells from c to VBA